# How to write unit test case for IBAction-XCode4

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode4

I want to write an unit test case to test the code in IBAction is executing properly or not.I did a sample to write logic test and it is working fine.I did not find any tutorial or guides to write application testing in Xcode 4.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have forgot to check the apple's site for the sample.This is the good link for the reference.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011742